# Can't get Powershell Out-File to format properly

Tags: powershell

The console output of my Powershell script looks like:

```
Item1
Item2
Item3
```

When I send the output to Out-File, I get:

```
Item1Item2Item3
```

How can I get it to format properly?

Comment: Can we see the rest of the script?

Comment: Open the file with a hex editor (e.g. [HxD](http://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/)). What does the content look like in hex?

Answer (score 0):

append "`r`n" for-each $row of $array before piping to out-file.

```
`r`n
```

aka powershell vbcrlf.